# Can anyone pls explain this ahk script logics/commands

Tags: autohotkey

Can anyone pls tell what is the purpose of `two sequential commas` and then `1` in the below given ahk script?

`Pause:: Suspend
Pause,,1
return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the script is suspended you can't unpause with that very same button because the hotkey is disabled.

In that case you need to use the **OperateOnUnderlyingThread** in the [Pause command parameters](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Pause.htm#Parameters):

`Pause,,1` makes a single button (in this case the button Pause or Break) work as both pause and unpause. It allows the Pause command to run a second time (i.e. to unpause).

```
Pause:: 
    Suspend ; disables or enables all or selected hotkeys and hotstrings.
    Pause,,1
return
```

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that the first parameter is blank.

https://lexikos.github.io/v1/docs/Language.htm#commands

> The comma separating the command name from its parameters is optional, except in the following cases:
>
> When it's necessary to prevent the line from being interpreted as a legacy assignment or assignment expression.
> `MsgBox, := This would be an assignment without the comma.`
>
> When the first parameter is blank.
> `MsgBox,, Second, Third`

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Pause.htm :

```
    Pause [, OnOffToggle, OperateOnUnderlyingThread]

OnOffToggle

    If blank or omitted, it defaults to Toggle. [...]
```

`Pause,,1` is the same as `Pause,Toggle,1`

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer.

Two commas mean there is a blank value, which in ahk means 'Off'. In other words it'd be perhaps same if it were: `Pause, Off, 1`

And `1` means `on`. That means, it is equal to
`Pause, Off, On`

I'm only 95% sure of the above.